# How to get an instance of MinecraftServer in Forge?

Tags: java, exception, instance, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to shutdown the server in code when an exception occurs. Getting an instance from the ServerStarting event is no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `MinecraftServer` argument available, use that. If you have an object with a method that returns `MinecraftServer` (e.g. `World#getMinecraftServer`), use that.

If all else fails, you can use `FMLCommonHandler#getMinecraftServerInstance`.

A good way to find out "how can I get a reference to this?" is to use your IDE: right click on the class name -> references -> find all in workspace.  The search results should return some hits. You may have to do this more than once, but in this case `World#getMinecraftServer` pops up and immediately you know that if you have a `World` object (and are on the server) you can get the server object from that.